# Please moderate Facebook comments on the SO page

Tags: support, status-completed, spam, facebook

Not a complaint or a whine, but a polite request because Facebook won't do it.

[image: Screenshot of SO's postcast 286 marketing, with scam comment underneath]

I reported the comment above, which was posted from a fake account using your name to entice people to send them crypto on the presumably fake promise of a 150% ROI. The wonderful folks at Facebook have decided that the comment "does not go against [their] Community Standards" and left it up.

Please remove it, and actively moderate your page in future so as to protect folks from scams.

---

Text:

> **Stack Overflów**
> We feel so lucky today, the first 3 people who are sending us 2 ETH are going to get back 3 ETH, when goal is reached we remove this!
>
> Wallet: *[ETH wallet ID redacted]*

Comment: I've got people looking into this. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: While you're at it, there's several other accounts using the name and logo (like [this one](https://www.facebook.com/stack.overflow.31392)). Might be worth having FB take those down too.

Comment: Heh, they even "declined the flag" on review. Just wow.

Comment: Declined what flag @AsteroidsWithWings? I also did flag this question to get a status-review, which was marked helpful. So I guess in your case it was just a mis-click.

Comment: @Catija this appears to be resolved, could you be so kind to adjust the status-tag accordingly?

Comment: @Luuklag I think Asteroids means a flag on Facebook, not here on SE. :)

Comment: How is it solved? Is one of the CMs on Facebook-duty semi-permanently now? Have they been checked just-this-once? Have comments been locked? What was the fix?

Comment: @Luuklag "they" = Facebook

Comment: @Mast based on Cat's comment, looks like someone from SE flagged and the flag was accepted on FB side and the comment deleted. I doubt SE appointed someone to monitor Facebook comments, they don't have enough employees for that.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard No, Catija's comment was clarifying my comment, in which I was referring to a twice-rejected review request triggered by myself.

Comment: _"I doubt SE appointed someone to monitor Facebook comments, they don't have enough employees for that."_ I'm actually not sure I agree with this. There appear to be staff whose sole job is to run the FB, Twitter and Blog outlets, and part of that role would surely be keeping at least half an eye on what is posted in comments underneath posts on those platforms. And it's not like there's a vast quantity of material coming out of SE on those platforms each day, nor more than a handful of comments posted on them by third parties.

Comment: When you realise you can't mod flag a facebook comment :(

Comment: Bounty expired after 7 days. Guess we're not to get any further clarification then.

Comment: Obvious scam is obvious. So why do anything? *A fool and his money are soon parted.* If you send 5000USD away because of a Facebook comment, you wouldn't have been able to keep those 5000USD for long anyway.